# Arduino Mega and Nextion display Serial communication

Tags: arduino, nextion

I'm working on Arduino Project using Nextion Display. At first It worked perfectly Arduino used to read and write data to display shown component, but for some reason Nextion doesn't send data to arduino anymore, I checked the Voltage supply common gnd, and wiring is perfect (TX ==> RX2 , RX ==> TX2).

I'm using Nextion Library which is working bu default for Arduino Mega , so no change is necessary.

here is the link to nextion library: https://github.com/itead/ITEADLIB_Arduino_Nextion

I'm sure the code doesn't contain any problems. It's all about serial communication from nextion display.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that the Nextion Display becomes unresponsive if you have any delays in your loop.

In several parts in the library there are timeouts of 100 millis if you have a larger time out like delay(120) you receive no data at all.

Furthermore the Library you are pointing to is related to using Serial2 look at my solution at github [Serial1 or Serial2 in external library reference](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/407)

This will solve your problem.